# C# Any substitutes for Boxing/Unboxing?

Tags: c#, boxing

My recent code is including a **lot of** [boxing and unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), as many of my variables are resolved at runtime. 
But I've read that boxing and unboxing is very expensive computationally, and so I want to ask if there is any other ways to box/unbox types?
And is this even a good practice to use it?

Comment: Are you having performance problems? Have you tried profiling your application to see if it has any bottlenecks? Concentrate on known bottlenecks first before worrying about something that may not be a problem at all.

Comment: #ShellShock
I don't think the performance is an issue in my program, but I think this is a rather interesting problem, and this might also help other users as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Generics`....

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

---

For example

```
List lst=new List();//non generic List accepts any kind of object
lst.Add(44);//this causes unnecessary boxing from int to object
lst.Add(100);//this causes unnecessary boxing from int to object
```

If you are sure that the list will always contain an integer you can use generics..

```
List<int> lst=new List<int>();
lst.Add(44);//no boxing or unboxing
lst.Add(100);//no boxing or unboxing
```

Comment: Agreed, generics is the way to go

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer.
However, the problem is that I'm not sure what kind of type my function is going to return (In my code, its either int OR string), and therefore I don't know what my list is going to contain.

Comment: @Janman So, _you_ introduce the generic types and/or generic methods. For example, if you have today a class `SomeClass` which contains some variables, method parameters etc. of type `object`, then change your class to `SomeClass<T>`, and inside the class change `object` to `T`. This way you get rid of boxing when `T` is `int`. Details depend on your exact code, of course, but you didn't provide a code example in your question.

Comment: #Jeppe Stig Nielsen
Thanks for answer. I'll definitely try that!

Answer (score -1):

In that specific question I could say use the more general type, in that case string and parse it to number if  its a number. More general approch is to create custom struct  or use tuple with field stating what its the real answer for each case like that , but its quit ugly.

Comment: Handing an int around as a string and parsing it is _not_ a good solution. You lose strong typing benefits and move potential errors from design/compile-time to runtime. This is not advisable. Also, I would be very surprised if parsing a string isn't far more computationally expensive than boxing/unboxing although I have no stats to back that up. (Sorry to be negative to a new user)